# Continous Integration Framework with Jenkins, SonarQube & Nexus in offline environment

Tags: jenkins, continuous-integration, offline, nexus, sonarqube

I'm implementing a framework using Jenkins, SonarQube & Nexus for multiple projects and different user groups in the company intranet. 
Hence there will be no internet connection to download the sonar plugins or updates allowed.

Anyone had try setting up similar framework as this framework is for many users hence I'm looking out for the best way to maintain this framework.
Below are the requirements I'm looking into:

- Ease of update/ download plugins
- Project Based User restriction to source code & sonarqube analysis
- Concurrent Build & Analysis of multiple projects at the same time.

Answer (score 0):

I maintain Jenkins, Sonar and Artifactory for my company.

Without outbound connections to the internet, the Jenkins server's ability to get modern plugins and updates will severely curtail project development as the "cool things" are happening there. With regards to maintaining plugins. You can easily drop in .hpi plugins manually to update them and bounce Jenkins. We run jenkins in a tomcat container and just drop in the war.

With Sonar, while there have been major updates to the software, compelling upgrade-now features related to Java have been few. It's another way of saying the product has been basically the same for 2+ years.

Keep in mind if you upgrade Sonar, you'll need to update the sonar runners in the Jenkins plugin.

Nexus vs. Artifactory. We use Artifactory. Jfrog's Artifactory may be a real benefit to you as it can act as a yum repository mirror in addition to a Maven repository. If you put Artifactory in a DMZ, you can then have it mirror updates for Jenkins and Sonar in Artifactory. You don't even have to keep the server int he DMZ the entire time. I assume you will have to do this anyway to mirror maven's repo1 from time to time.

Comment: Just fyi Nexus has equivalent Yum support to Artifactory.